# Xilinx Virtex 6 - assigning pins FPGA

Tags: fpga

I am writing a basic logic program to a Virtex 6. It is a simple half adder with two inputs (A,B) and two outputs (Signal, Carryout). I would like to assign A, B to two switches and Signal, Carryout to two LEDs.

I have written the program and now trying to assign those relevant pins in PlanAhead 13.3. I am struggling with identifying the sites for two LEDs and two switches.

I can identify locations of switches on the board, which are labelled SW3, SW4 - but I am not sure how to find the location on the device's pin assignments, even with the datasheet: http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug365.pdf

Any help would be useful -

Comment: You need the schematic for the board.

Comment: This is why I attached that datasheet... It's on a ML605 if this helps. I.e. this does not help me identify a switch. http://www.schematicsymbol.com/pdfs/6VSX315T-FF(G)1156.pdf

Comment: You still need the board schematic. Without it, the question cannot be answered and should be closed.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you are looking for switches and LEDs in an FPGA datasheet??
Why are you not looking at the [evaluation kit schematics](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/xtp052_ml605_schematics.pdf) as Leon has suggested?
Pages 13 & 31 may be of help.

Comment: What Xilinx board are you using?

Answer (score 3):

The [hardware user guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ug534.pdf) for the board documents all of the I/O connections to the FGPA. In particular, the switches and LEDs are documented in chapter 17, which starts on page 49.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else is pointing out, the [Hardware User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ug534.pdf) is the documentation that talks about this. Additionally, you could look at the [Board Schematic](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/xtp052_ml605_schematics.pdf) itself. You might also look at some of the [reference designs](http://www.xilinx.com/products/boards/ml605/reference_designs_12.3_archive.htm) that Xilinx provides.

That being said, SW3 and SW4 are not the switches you are looking for. Instead, you'll want SW5 through SW10, which are user definable. These are described in User Pushbutton Switches under section 17.

```
Pin Name   Schematic Net Name   Pushbutton Switch Name
--------   ------------------   ----------------------
A19        GPIO_SW_N            SW5.2
A18        GPIO_SW_S            SW6.2
G17        GPIO_SW_E            SW7.2
H17        GPIO_SW_W            SW8.2
G26        GPIO_SW_C            SW9.2
H10        CPU_RESET            SW10.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the information you need at Xilinx's web site for the board:

[ML605 13.2 and Earlier Documentation](http://www.xilinx.com/products/boards/ml605/reference_designs.htm)

You can find the "ML605 Master UCF (rdf0041) (ZIP)" which is the 3rd one from the bottom of the list.